Maintaining image aspect ratio when max-width is less than true width
I have a large image whose width in CSS is set by width: 1024px and also controlled by a max-width: 100%. The height is also specified in px so as to allow the browser to render the page correctly first time without any re-rendering. That does seem to me to be very sensible. But what do I do if the max-width turns out to be less than 1024, as I’m told that the height, being specified in px, will cause the image to be displayed with a distorted aspect ratio? If I set the height: auto, I’m assuming that will fix the problem but I’m also assuming that then there will be a re-rendering. Is that correct? If so, is there some way out of this?

Have you tried setting aspect ratio rather than height?

Have you tried anything at all?

This is an interesting read. The article recommends using height: auto in CSS and adding width and height attributes to the <img> tag in your HTML. Browsers can automatically calculate the correct aspect ratio before downloading the image itself. No layout shift.
Note that CSS overrides HTML when it comes to widths and heights.
